# Make the C preprocessor ignore certain #include directives

Tags: c, gcc, include, build-process, c-preprocessor

I use a parser generator here, that unfortunately insists on putting a

```
#include <some/file.h>
```

at the top of every generated source file. The header has since long been renamed. While it is no problem forcing the compiler (gcc) to use the new header with `-include new/header.h`, removing the above directive from every generated file complicates the build-process.

Is there a way to tell gcc to simply ignore `some/file.h`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No.  You can post-process your generated file - I say: NO!!!

Or you can just add '.' to your system include directories (or whatever your local include path is - make sure it's also a <> system include path).

Then make a 'some' directory and stick your own permanent 'file.h' in there that has 1 line for #include  and get rid of your -include.

I'm guess there's some reason that might not work - cause it seems like the more straight forward and understandable thing to do before using -include.  Especially since you can comment the pass-through file to explain what's going on.

Answer (score 5):

Replace `some/file.h` with an empty file.

Comment: No, because it's a system header. But with -I. it's possible to make gcc find it anyway. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Why not make a symlink from some/file.h to new/header.h, and remove the -include directive?

Comment: Because it used to be a system header living in /usr/include. It shouldn't be necessary to modifie /usr/include just to compile some app.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <some/file.h>
```

may start as something like

```
#ifndef _FILE_H_
#define _FILE_H_
```

If so, just add `#define _FILE_H_` before the `#include` command and it should ignore it.
I'm not sure whether this is the best solution, though.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [preprocessor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_preprocessor) directives like #if and #ifdef and gcc **-DSYMBOL=value** command line flag.

In example, if you compile using *gcc -DREQUIRE_STDC=1 -o myfile.o myfile.c*, and your .c file contains:

```
#if defined(REQUIRE_STDC) && defined(__STDC__)
#include "some/file.h"
#else
#include "another/file.h"
#endif /* defined(REQUIRE_STDC) && defined(__STDC__) */
```

It will compile using "some/file.h" if have both **STDC** and REQUIRE_STDC symbols defined. Also your header may include the proper directive to avoid multiple inclusions of the same file:

```
#ifndef MY_HEADER_FILE
#define MY_HEADER_FILE 1

/* your C declarations here */

#endif /* MY_HEADER_FILE */
```

Also, you could the [gcc preprocessor](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/) manual.

Comment: Thats possible for normal source files. In my case the source is generated on the fly and I don't have the necessary control over its resulting output.